# Can anyone suggest an XSLT template suitable for rendering XML as "XML"

Tags: xml, xslt

Looking for an XSLT template that I can fling a bit of XML at and it will render just like when Firefox says "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below." - i.e. a kind of code layout view.

Any ideas?

Cheers...

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/10913)? And [here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=293645&f=38) is a post with the local location.

Comment: Maybe! I'll try it and let you know...

Comment: Mmmmm. Slightly struggling to get it to work. Here's the php I'm using. $this->mem->Plan is some XML that takes the form "<plan>....</plan>" 
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>\n");
echo("<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"/assets/templates/vanilla.xsl\"?>\n");
echo $this->mem->Plan;

Comment: See the second link? You will need to get the CSS file and change the `chrome:` links.

Comment: Ah - thanks! Getting there! <div id="header" dir="&locale.dir;"> is causing trouble...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to generate HTML that when viewed in the browser displays a pretty-indented XML, then do have a look how **[the Xpath Visualizer](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html)** does this -- both for Firefox and IE. In the FF download the XSLT stylesheet to look at is mozDss5.xsl

Answer (score 0):

You should set the content-type in the header of your document to "application/xml" or "text/xml"